# Why is my bootstrap modal component not showing in another Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have two single-file components, one is for the modal body, and another is a list of cards that use that and dynamically load values in that.

Here is the `imageModal.vue`, mostly boilerplate bootstrap.

```
<template>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" @click.prevent="close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="close">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>

import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

export default {
    name: 'imageModal',
    methods: {
        close() {
            this.$emit('close');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And here is the `tile.vue` component using it.

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="gallery justify-content-center list-group-flush">
      <li class="mb-1 pics" v-for="post in postsWithPreview" v-bind:key="post.data.id">
        <div class="card" @click.prevent="showModal">
          <img :src="post.data.preview.images[0].source.url.replace('amp;s', 's')" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <imageModal v-if="modalVisible"/>
  </div>
</template>



<script>

  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

  import imageModal from '@/components/imageModal.vue'

  const axios = require('axios')


  const baseURL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers.json"
  export default {
    name: 'tile',
    props: {
      msg: String
    },
    data() {
      return {
        modalVisible: false,
        postObjList: []
      }
    },
    components: {
      imageModal,
    },
    created() {
      axios.get(baseURL)
        .then(response => {
          this.postObjList = response.data.data.children
          console.log(this.postObjList)
          console.log(this.postsWithPreview)
        })
    },
    methods: {
      showModal() {
        this.modalVisible = true
      },
      closeModal() {
        this.modalVisible = false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But when I click on the image cards, nothing happens. What is happening here? And, is there a better way of doing this?
I want to make a dynamic modal that will contain the same image as the card which is clicked, along with some additional information on the card.

Comment: bootstrap modals works with `jquery`

Comment: Tried. Changed all open and close functions with `jquery('#exampleModal').modal()`, still does not work

Comment: `jquery, bootstrap.js and popperjs` should be installed as dependency o by cdn.

Comment: They are installed.

Comment: jquery should be imported in your component

Comment: DId just that. Still not doing anything.

Comment: @shiladityabasu Were able to figure out the issue? I am also facing the same issue where I am unable to access the Bootstrap component in another component.